# divide a large group of people into subgroups based on two parameter

Tags: python, dataset, clustering

**note in advance**: I'm new to data-analysis and although my major *civil engineering* taught me about statistics, I did not apply it the way I would have encountered in real life, or in this field of work. I don't have any person in my circle of contacts that I can get advice from, that's why I'm asking here.

**the description:**

I have a dataset of a large group of people *nearly 200*, and that I'm trying to arrange these people into group, (each group is from 12 to 14 person). the dataset contains parameters of `birthyear` and `home-state` *all numerical*.

a previous code that I worked on achieved that be just shuffle them into groups. but the problem was that: (one group could contain people mostly from one state, and other groups could be non-representative of that state). and I don't actually like how it worked, as I would describe it *"lazy grouping"*

question 1:
**so, If I have a the large group, how can I split it into subgroups with the same properties *or near enough* the large group??**

**here are some histograms that show my case:**

[image: histogram of home_state's count]

[image: histogram of birthyears' count]

[image: 2D histogram of home_state AND birthyears count]

**something I'm thinking of:**

although the large group can give me the mean/var/std, but because I'm subtracting from it to make subgroups, this means that I should not lookup for *ideal group*. and that my solution should be to fix uniform shuffling. so I searched and saw that `numpy` can offer weighted shuffling. but it was not as quite as I expected. and by so I need a to make a shuffling function for my purpose.

**the algorithm that should work for me:**

```
# df = 'MY_ORIGINAL_DF'
home_state = df.home_state
birthyears = df.birthyear

home_state_count = home_state.value_counts()
home_state_normalized = home_state_count / home_state_count.sum()
#                         +-----+-----+-----+-----+
#                         |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  | corresponding home_state
# home_state_normalized = +-----+-----+-----+-----+
#                         | 0.1 | 0.4 | 0.2 | 0.2 | its propbablity
#                         +-----+-----+-----+-----+
birthyears_count = birthyears.value_counts()
birthyears_normalized = birthyears_count / birthyears_count.sum()
#                         +------+------+------+
#                         | 1970 | 1980 | 1990 | corresponding birthyears
# birthyears_normalized = +------+------+------+
#                         | 0.60 | 0.10 | 0.30 | its propbablity
#                         +------+------+------+

## calculating weighted_matrix:
#                    +-----+                                           +------+------+------+
#                    | 0.1 |                                           | 0.06 | 0.01 | 0.03 |
#                    +-----+                                           +------+------+------+
#                    | 0.4 |                 +------+------+------+    | 0.24 | 0.04 | 0.12 |
# weighterd_matrix = +-----+ (outer_product) | 0.60 | 0.10 | 0.30 |  = +------+------+------+
#                    | 0.2 |                 +------+------+------+    | 0.12 | 0.02 | 0.06 |
#                    +-----+                                           +------+------+------+
#                    | 0.2 |                                           | 0.12 | 0.02 | 0.06 |
#                    +-----+                                           +------+------+------+
```

now each cell of `weighterd_matrix` corresponds to the pair (birthyear, home_state). (and to be clear: I know how to apply matrix multiplication in python, it's not a problem, but I made it look visually easy to read)

question 2: **how can I apply shuffling to my dataframe based on this weighted matrix??**

### things you can help me with:

- suggest topics I can search about.
- suggest how I can continue with my implementation of `weighted_matrix`.
- suggest docs that can guide me.
- be positive. *I'm a messy-thought person and I tried so much to organize me problem and my description*

Comment: Welcome to the site @Abdulrahman Sheikho. I would suggest investigating K-means clustering, as this seems applicable based on your description.  scikit-learn is documented here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html and searching k-means clustering tutorials is a good start. hth.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.